# Maven building xml-structure?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

Is there an easier way and/or helper editor to add xml-configuration to pom.xml?
The problem is once you find a solution  let say f.e. you find that setting :

```
<skipTest>false</skipTest>
```

The code above disables skipping tests. Now, how do you build up the full configuration of surefire plugin if you have nothing about it in your pom.xml.

The "skipTest" is inside the section "plugin" which is inside "plugins" which is inside... and also there is data to be filled in between. Anyways, the Eclipse editor cant help you with that! All the examples on the Maven site and in SO assume you know the "upward hierarchy", which apparently is not the case.

I'm not trolling it is very frustrating to find a solution to your problem, but being unable to reconstruct the xml to make it work?

How do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are quite a lot of examples on the Maven site, concerning your example this should be helpful:[maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html)

I am not aware of any helper plugins/programs that could do this for you, except basic adding of dependencies with rudimentary setup. Reading through the documentation seems to be the best approach here I guess.